# My query through GraphQL is returning data properly on my Web application, but not on Mobile. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I built an email button to send the user their receipt of their choices that they voted for in an election. The function returns the proper information on web. It returns the election name, ballot name, and the option names. The data for those titles and names is pulled from a query with GraphQL. The problem is when there are ballots with multiple choices, for example 3, the receipt shows 3 option names, but they are all the same.

[Receipt from Web app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT6pg.png)

[Receipt from Mobile app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YGWV.png)

When I console log the data from the query, it shows the same receipt information that is shown above, the names repeat on Mobile but not on Web. I have compared the code for both functions and queries in both the Web and Mobile, and cannot find any differences, I have even copied the code from the working Web app and pasted it into the Mobile app with no success. The Mobile app is built with Expo and React Native.

I'm stumped at this point and cannot understand how the same query can return different data.

```
//graphql
import {
  ELECTION_REPORT,
  MY_VOTE,
  FETCH_BALLOTS,
} from '../../graph/queries/elections';
import { SEND_EMAIL } from '../../graph/mutations/elections';

const ElectionsComponent = ({ item, navigation }) => {
  const { id, title, endDate, startDate } = item;

** THESE HOLD THE DATA FOR THE USER AND UNION **
  const unionState = useUnionState();
  const userState = useUserState();

  const [setEmail, setNewEmail] = useState(userState.profile.email);
  const [receipt, setReceipt] = useState();
  const [timeVoted, setTimeVoted] = useState();
  const [dataReady, setDataReady] = useState(false);
  const [storedBallot, setStoredBallot] = useState();

  const { loading } = useQuery(ELECTION_REPORT, {
    variables: {
      unionID: unionState.id,
      electionID: id,
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      if (data.electionReport) {
        data.electionReport.forEach((report) => {
          if (report.respondentID == userState.id) {
            setReceipt(report.recieptID);
          }
        });
      }
    },
  });

  const { loading: ballotLoading, data: ballotData } = useQuery(FETCH_BALLOTS, {
    variables: {
      unionID: unionState.id,
      electionID: id,
    },
    onCompleted: () => {

// THIS IS WHERE THE STORED BALLOT IS CREATED

      const mappedBallots = new Map();
      if (ballotData && ballotData.ballots) {
        ballotData.ballots.forEach((val) =>
          mappedBallots.set(val.id, { title: val.title, votedFor: [**Titles populate here**] })
        );
      }
      setStoredBallot(mappedBallots);
      getMyVote();
    },
  });

  const [getMyVote, { loading: userVoteLoading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery(
    MY_VOTE,
    {
      variables: {
        unionID: unionState.id,
        electionID: id,
        receiptID: receipt,
      },
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      onCompleted: () => {
          data.myVote.forEach((vote) => {
            setTimeVoted(vote.respondedAt);
            if (storedBallot.has(vote.ballotID)) {
              const value = storedBallot.get(vote.ballotID);
              value.votedFor.push(vote.votedFor.title);
              storedBallot.set(vote.ballotID, value);
            }
          });
        setDataReady(true);
      },
    }
  );

  const [sendEmail, { loading: submitLoading }] = useMutation(SEND_EMAIL, {
    onCompleted: () => {
          // Shows the email was sent successfully
    },
    onError: (error) => {
          // Shows if the email mutation failed
    },
  });


  const submitEmail = () => {
    if (dataReady) {

      let content = `<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;margin: 20px 0">
        <img src="${
          unionState.information.imageURL
        }" alt="Union Logo" style="width: 125px;height: 125px;border-radius: 10px">
      </div>\n

        <h1 style="font-style: italic;text-align: center;line-height: 1.3">${title}</h1>\n

        <p style="margin-top:20px">On ${format(
          new Date(timeVoted),
          'PPPPp'
        )}</p>`;

      storedBallot.forEach((poll) => {
        content =
          content +
          `<h3 style="margin-top:40px">For ${poll.title}</h3>\n  <=== THIS IS THE OPTION TITLE
          <p>You selected:</p>`;
        poll.votedFor.map((option) => {
          content = content + `<p style="margin-left:30px">${option}</p>`;
        });
      });

      content =
        content +
        `<h5 style="margin-top:80px">Receipt ID:</h5>\n
        <p>${receipt}</p>`;

      sendEmail({
        variables: {
          email: [setEmail],
          sender: 'Requested Vote Receipt',
          subject: 'Here is what you selected',
          content: content,
        },
      });
    }
  };

 
  return (
    <Card>

          <Text>
            Receipt ID: {receipt.slice(-5)}
          </Text>

          <BlackButton
            title='Email My Receipt'
            onPress={() => submitEmail()}
          />

    </Card>
  );
};

export default ElectionsComponent;
```

And this is the Query

```
export const ELECTION_REPORT = gql`
  query electionReport(
    $unionID: UnifiedID!
    $electionID: UnifiedID!
    $ballotID: UnifiedID
    $reportType: String
  ) {
    electionReport(
      unionID: $unionID
      electionID: $electionID
      ballotID: $ballotID
      reportType: $reportType
    ) {
      id
      ballotID
      respondentID
      imageURL
      optionID
      respondedAt
      mode
      ipAddress
      userAgent
      respondent {
        id
        firstName
      }
      votedFor {
        title
      }
      recieptID
    }
  }
`;

export const MY_VOTE = gql`
  query myVote(
    $unionID: UnifiedID!
    $electionID: UnifiedID!
    $receiptID: String!
  ) {
    myVote(unionID: $unionID, electionID: $electionID, receiptID: $receiptID) {
      id
      ballotID
      respondentID
      imageURL
      optionID
      respondedAt
      mode
      ipAddress
      userAgent
      respondent {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
      }
      votedFor {
        title
      }
      recieptID
      abstained
    }
  }
`;
```

The way the data is returned, each ballot comes back as an object, if the ballot has multiple selected options, an object will be created for each option the user selected, with the same ballot id. I then group the ballot id's together when I create the storedBallot, this then holds the array of the "votedFor" titles. If there are any suggestions as to why this does not work, I'm all ears.

Comment: I suspect Expo is to blame

Comment: no queries fault, strange/unnecessary data/state management ... log your state changes ... prepare working, editable [example]